# A basis for $\mathbb{F}_2^{2^n}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, finite-fields

The vector space $\mathbb{F}_2^{2^n}$ can be identified with the space of functions $f:\mathbb{F}_2^{n}\to \mathbb{F}_2$. Consider the functions $f_S$ defined for every bistring $y\in \mathbb{F}_2^n$ by $f_y(x)=
1$ if $\sum x_i y_i=0\pmod 2$ and $0$ else.

Do the functions $f_S$ form a basis for $\mathbb{F}_2^{2^n}$ (under the identification)? If not, what subspace do these functions span?

Edit: As pointed out in the comments, the vectors generated by these functions always have even Hamming weight. So the correct question is whether they always span the $2^n-1$ dimensional subspace consisting of all such vectors.

Comment: Did you try to figure it out for some values of $n$? $1$? $2$?

Comment: Well, that was a very good point... It turns out that $n=2$ already answers this question negatively. The space spanned is $3$ dimensional and consists of all vectors with an even Hamming weight. In fact, it is easy to see that this constraint holds in general. Still, the question is now whether these functions always span the subspace of even Hamming weight.

Comment: Well, doing small computations (and specially these, which you can automate) is always a good idea...!

Comment: Yeah, I think this is a case of confirmation bias. I really wanted this to be true. :-)

Comment: The functions $f_y$ (together with the constant functions) span the first order Reed-Muller code. A tiny subspace of the space of all Boolean functions in $n$ variables. Tiny, as in when $n\to\infty$. The polynomial $f(x)=x_1x_2$ is not in the span when $n\ge2$. Yet it has an even weight, when $n\ge3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that $f_y=1-y^\top$, therefore $f_0=1$ and $f_x-f_y=(y-x)^\top$, and thus \begin{align}\operatorname{span}(f_y\,:\, y\in\Bbb F_2^n)&=\operatorname{span}(1,\{v^\top\}_{v\in\Bbb F_2^n})=\operatorname{span}(1,\Bbb F_2^{n*})=\\&=\operatorname{aff}(\Bbb F^n_2,\Bbb F_2)\end{align}

Where the latter is the space of affine maps $\Bbb F_2^n\to\Bbb F_2$. The dimension of this space is $n+1$, while there are $2^n$ maps $f_y$. So they are linearly independent if and only if $2^n=n+1$, i.e. if and only if $n=0$ or $n=1$.